# How to chose the right analysis and tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

In R I have two datasets `data1` and `data2`. The datasets contain data of user, a game they have played, and the number of time they have played it. There are 10 games (same games in each dataset) and 1000 users in `data1` and 2100 users in `data2`.
So when we type

```
head(data1)
```

we get

```
user   game   number
145    2      10 
400    3      54
 14    2      9
351    9      101
```

So for example user `145` has played game `2` exactly `10` times.
We get a similar result for `head(data2)`.

I want to compare the two datasets. Want to see if there are game in `data1` that are more popular (has been played more) than in `data2`.

One way to do this could be: for `game==1` take the sum of the numbers it has been played in `data1` and `data2` and make a Pearson Chi-sq test to see if there is a dependence. Is that a good analysis or is there other analyses to use ?

Comment: Some clarification would be helpful. I've assumed that the 10 games are same in each dataset. Why aren't you interested in a ranking based on the total popularity of the games? What is the basis for comparison between these two data sources and how would that factor into your analysis? In other words, based on some distinguishing information such as demographics or context-specific factors (e.g., price, ease of use, and so on), can an analysis be done that would provide insight into why game usage is different between these two datasets?

Comment: The 10 games are the same in each datasets. The price are the same for all games. What exactly do you mean with total popularity of the games?

Comment: If everything is the same between these two sources of information, why bother to break them out separately? "Total" popularity refers to a ranking based on collapsing the two datasets into one.

Comment: data1 contains users that stopped played and data2 contains users that still plays the games. Therefore it would be interesting to compare these two groups and see if some game 'causes' users to stop playing.

Comment: Ok. Then your target variable -- the thing you want to predict -- could be "Playing" versus "Stopped Playing" and collapsing the information into one dataset makes sense. I think you need more information or features to be able to understand what's driving the choices here and not just "game played." If you have some hypotheses as to why players have terminated or are churning, do you have the data to support and test those hypotheses? If not, consider making recommendations to your IT people to set up a process that would collect the relevant data so that a meaningful analysis is possible.

Comment: I have more supporting data such as if a player winning or loosing a game. But first I want to investigate the question: "Does a specific game/games have an impact on a user stop playing and sign out." One way to answer this question could be to compare data1 and data2 with Pearson's Independence Test ?

Comment: Do you mean a test of independence (using a Pearson chi-square) between a specific game and "playing/stopped playing" target variable? That would be useful for exploratory purposes but a logistic regression would provide a more robust, multivariate answer.

Comment: Yes I would use Pearson's Chi-square for a specific game, fe game==1 I should get a p-value from chisq.test( c( "number game1 has been played in data1", "total number in data1" ) , c("number game1 has been played in data2" , "total number in data2")  ) , however I don't know if I should use rbind or cbind for this test. I assume cbind is the correct way to get the correct p-value. For making a logistic regression model I can't see what one should select as input variable to get the output-variable "stopped played" / "still playing".

Comment: Tests of independence are symmetric with respect to rows and columns.